# Need to get a boolean value from XML using DataContractSerializer's ReadObject() method

Tags: xml, wcf, boolean, datacontractserializer

I have a simple XML document that I want to read into an object using the DataContractSerializer in .NET.

`<Person>`
    `<Enabled>true</Enabled>`
    `<Name>John Smith</Name>`
`</Person>`

When I read the object, the Enabled field is always false even though the node value is "true."  How does one define XML that will probably deserialize into a boolean true when ReadObject() is called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how you define your class. If you define it as follows, it should read correctly.

```
public class StackOverflow_8012009
{
    const string XML = "<Person><Enabled>true</Enabled><Name>John Smith</Name></Person>";
    [DataContract(Namespace = "", Name = "Person")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Person[Enabled={0},Name={1}]", this.Enabled, this.Name);
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Person));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(XML));
        object obj = dcs.ReadObject(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```